# How to get Head Title value using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have html page and i want head title value on page load using jquery, see my below html code

```
<html>
<head>`enter code here`
<title>Home - chcc</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>


<input type='button' value='find div .A1' id='button1'>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 18):

You don't even need jQuery for this. Just use the `document.title` property

Answer (score 7):

If you want jQuery instead raw javascript, use `$("head title")[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can select the Title tag by using only Javascript like the Following:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
// Then you can print it on the screen
alert(title);
```